# Is it possible to add an attribute to an XML Root using nusoap's call() function?

Tags: service, nusoap, fedex

I am creating a class that will be utilizing the Fedex Web Services.  I am attempting to communicate through the nusoap php class's nosoapclient() function, passing it a wsdl file.  It seems Fedex requires a namespace attribute in the document root of a request.

I can use nusoap's call() function and pass it an XML string as the PARAMETER agrument which WILL WORK properly.  I would rather pass an array through as the PARAMETER argument, and this is where I am running into an issue.

Is it possible to pass an array through nusoap's call() function and also include a namespace attribute in the root?

**FEDEX RateRequest PHP exerpt**
*The following is to give an idea of what I am trying to do and not actual code*

```
$client = new nusoapclient('RateRequest_v9.wsdl',true);
//Thought this would work but to no avail.
//$request_array is a multi-associative array with keys as required XML tag names and values as the tags inner value, did not include as it is irrelevant to this problem
//$root_attr = array('xmlns'=>'http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v9');
//$parameters = array('RateRequest'=>new soapval('RateRequest',false,$request_array,false,false,$root_attr));

$parameters = array('RateRequest'=>$request_array);

//Have tried with and without the third argument - which is the for the namespace
$response = $client->call('getRates',$parameters,'http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v9');
```

**FEDEX RateRequest XML excerpt**
*The following is not the full XML (look at the RateRequest tag toward the end to see the difference)*

*INCORRECT FORMAT*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v9"><SOAP-ENV:Body><RateRequest>...</RateRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

*CORRECT FORMAT*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v9"><SOAP-ENV:Body><RateRequest xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v9">...</RateRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

*My apologies in advance if I have missed this conversation elsewhere but I have been scouring the net and trying everything I could think of to make it work, if its not possible any suggestions?  Thank you in advance for your assistance.*